# Extension methods with generics in Dart: Value of type dynamic can't be returned from method

Tags: generics, dart, extension-methods

Given this

```dart
extension<T> on List<T> {
  List<T> addAtTheEnd(T value) {
    return this.addAllAtTheEnd(<T>[value]);
  }

  List<T> addAllAtTheEnd(List<T> values) {
    return [
      ...this,
      ...values,
    ];
  }
}
```

In the code editor the `this.addAllAtTheEnd(<T>[value])` is underlined and it's saying:

`A value of type 'List<dynamic>' can't be returned from method 'addAtTheEnd' because it has a return type of 'List<T>'.`

This does not sound logical to me, as the `addAllAtTheEnd` method does not have compile errors, I explicitly define the type of generics on the call site (`addAtTheEnd`) and I am using `this` to indicate what type I am calling the method on.

Why is this not working and how can I make it work?

Comment: I'm not sure why `dartanalyzer` is complaining about `List<dynamic>`, but it seems that you can fix it by changing `this.addAllAtTheEnd(...)` to just `addAllAtTheEnd(...)`.  BTW, you could just use `List<T>.append` for single elements and `+=` for appending another `List`.

Comment: I know about the `append` function, I was aiming for creating a minimal reproducible example, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I will see if it works without `this`. The reason I wrote it using `this` is because smart completion did not work without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, omitting `this` solves, just like `jamesdlin` suggested in the comments.

---

I tested it thoroughly, and these are the results:

This compiles:

```dart
...
  List<T> addAtTheEnd(T value) {
    return addAllAtTheEnd([value]);
  }
```

This does **not**:

```dart
...
  List<T> addAtTheEnd(T value) {
    final thiz = this;
    return thiz.addAllAtTheEnd([value]);
  }
```

because it is equivalent to the following, where the issue is more clear:

```dart
...
  List<T> addAtTheEnd(T value) {
    final List thiz = this;
    return thiz.addAllAtTheEnd([value]);
  }
```

But declaring the type explicitly works:

```dart
...
  List<T> addAtTheEnd(T value) {
    final List<T> thiz = this;
    return thiz.addAllAtTheEnd([value]);
  }
```

Fun fact: `dart linter` complains for the solution if you have that lint rule enabled, namely [`omit_local_variable_types`](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/omit_local_variable_types.html).

So the correct and explicit usage for calling `this` is the following:

```
...
  List<T> addAtTheEnd(T value) {
    // ignore: omit_local_variable_types
    final List<T> thiz = this;
    return thiz.addAllAtTheEnd([value]);
  }
```

If you use it the following way with inline explicit cast:

```dart
  List<T> addAtTheEnd(T value) {
    return (this as List<T>).addAllAtTheEnd([value]);
  }
```

You get a warning for [`unnecessary cast`](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#unnecessary_cast), where the autofix gladly helps you to convert your code to not be compilable.

Comment: Man. you made my day! Thank you.